# Global Function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I do this in every uitableviewcontroller I have.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor= [UIColor blueColor];
UIImageView *headerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = headerView;
```

Is there a way I can create a custom class that does this for me? Like such

```
[StyleDefaults setNavStyles];
```

where

```
@implementation StyleDefaults

+(void) setNavStyle {

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor= [UIColor blueColor];
    UIImageView *headerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kheader]];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = headerView;

}

@end
```

I get this error: request for member 'navigationBar' in something not a structure or union

I know why I get this, but is there a way around this issue?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you move that code to another class, `self` is no longer the UITableViewController that it was in.  You can pass a reference to the UITableViewController into the method so it can access those navigation properties.

Add a parameter of type UIViewController (UITableViewControllers are subclasses of those) and replace `self` with the parameter:

```
+(void) setNavStyle:(UIViewController *)viewController {    
    viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor= [UIColor blueColor];
    UIImageView *headerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kheader]];
    viewController.navigationItem.titleView = headerView;
}
```

Then call the method from the UITableViewControllers like this:

```
[StyleDefaults setNavStyle:self];
```

Comment: Much better solution than categories.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a category for this task. [See this tip on MacDeveloper](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html)
Your interface would look like this:

```
@interface UIViewController (myDefaultStyle)
-(void) setupMyStyle;
@end
```

and the implementation could look like this:

```
@implementation UIViewController (myDefaultStyle)    
  
 -(void) setupMyStyle {

   self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor= [UIColor blueColor];
   UIImageView *headerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kheader]];
   self.navigationItem.titleView = headerView;

 }
```

Now everything you'd need to do in your actual view controller is import the category and call `[self setupMyStyle]` where it makes sense.
While it servers the same purpose as passing a reference to self into a static function,it's clearer code and maybe even a notch faster.

Comment: Do **not** use a category for this.  Or, if you really really want to go down that path, **always prefix your methods with something unique**.  Adding that method in a category will make every instance of that class and subclass respond to that method.  If you happen to name your method the same as an existing method (or one that comes along in the future), your app will break in mysterious ways.